# A calendar embedded in OS X desktop that allows me to cross off days I workout - does something like this exist?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, calendar

I'm getting into an exercise routine and in the past I've found it helpful to cross off the days tha I do exercise on a calendar. It occurred to me that I spend far more time looking at my macbook desktop than at my bedroom wall and would like to know if anyone is aware of an application that will allow me to have a calendar with at least one full month showing at a time embedded on my desktop, and allow me to cross off the days that I work out?

Answer (score 1):

Use the build in calendar (came with osx), open it, click on the (+) sign to add new event for today, type worked, then you have lots of options to use if you want to, but that is the simplest way to do it.
You can even make a new calendar specific to your activity.
You can email the event to yourself, etc...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd really like to find a solution that's a bit more elegant though. The point of having it on the desktop is that it's a constant reminder of my goals as I'm working throughout the day. Opening an application like calendar doesn't work for that purpose.

Comment: So you want it as desktop wall paper?. Also, as for the reminders, those you can set up in the calendar, inclusive of automatically sending you emails, and messages, and SMS all the way till it gets annoying. For example there will be a popup window on you desktop, and it keeps popping till you kill it. You do not have to open the calendar, it can stay open all the time, in the background.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions for workarounds. Really I'm quite wedded to the idea of a calendar that is embedded in the desktop and allows me to cross off somehow the days that I do exercise. I know that something like this can be done without too much difficulty on linux, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do is on OS X as well, even if no app for it exists yet.

Comment: I do not know, but I will do some searching for you. Meanwhile do not forget the exercises. PS. does the app has to be for free ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Fantastical](https://flexibits.com/fantastical) fits the need?

It still doesn't allow for an embedded calendar that is fully visible all the time on the Desktop, however it does add it to the menubar for quick access.  It integrates with your current calendar (iCal, Calendar, Outlook, etc) and allows for quick adding of appointments by clicking the menubar icon and typing a bit.

If I were making this solution for myself I'd imagine it along the lines of this:

- Using Calendar / iCal, create a new calendar called "workouts"
- Download and install Fantastical
- Click on the menu bar icon for Fantastical
- Ensure that the calendar is set to workouts
- Type in something along the lines of "Worked out today" and save it

Seems like that would work relatively well, allowing for convenience without being too intrusive.